# Primefaces autoComplete menu appended to body

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I have a list of autoComplete fields:

```
    <div id="myList" style="height:200px; overflow:scroll;">
        <p:autoComplete minQueryLength="3" dropdown="true" style="width: 360px;" forceSelection="true" queryDelay="200" value="first" completeMethod="#{ myTest.autocompleteServer}" /><br />
        <p:autoComplete minQueryLength="3" dropdown="true" style="width: 360px;" forceSelection="true" queryDelay="200" value="second" completeMethod="#{ myTest.autocompleteServer}" /><br />
        <p:autoComplete minQueryLength="3" dropdown="true" style="width: 360px;" forceSelection="true" queryDelay="200" value="third" completeMethod="#{ myTest.autocompleteServer}" /><br />
        <p:autoComplete minQueryLength="3" dropdown="true" style="width: 360px;" forceSelection="true" queryDelay="200" value="fourth" completeMethod="#{ myTest.autocompleteServer}" /><br />
    </div>
```

The ammount of autoComplete lines is dynamic (more than the four shown).

My problem is that when the autoComplete suggestion menu is open and I try to scroll (using the mouse's scroller) the parent DIV (with the id="myList"), the DIV scrolls, but the autoComplete menu stays in it's place, since it's appended to the body with position:absolute.

My question is, whether there's a way (like in jQuery UI, where you can use the "ui-front" class) to append the menu to the parent DIV ("myList").

Thanks in advance,

-Daniel